# Is there a more concise way to concatenate these strings in Cocoa?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

```
NSString *latitude = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%g°", coordinate.latitude];
NSString *longitude = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%g°", coordinate.longitude];
self.pointLabel.text = [latitude stringByAppendingString:@", "];
self.pointLabel.text = [self.pointLabel.text stringByAppendingString:longitude];
```

Comment: NSString* latitude = [[NSNumber numberWithDouble:coordinate.latitude] stringValue]; // this will not leak as yours does.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
self.pointLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%gº, %gº", coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude];
```

Comment: what is that symbol after the g?

Comment: @MarshallMoutenot option-0.  It's the masculine ordinal indicator.  It would probably be better to use shift-cmd-8, which is the actual degree sign.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Vote for me ;)

```
self.pointLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat @"%g°, %g°", coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude];
```

Answer (score 2):

Yep.

```
self.pointLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat @"%g°, %g°", coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude];
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what the other three said, your code is leaking two objects. Please review the [memory management rules](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html).